# C# ListView Tile Width 100%?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, tiles, fluid-layout

i have a ListView set to Tileview. The ListView width is 300 and so is the tile width.

This works fine when the number of tiles does not overflow resulting in a scrollbar.

When it does overflow however, when the vertical scrollbar appears, a horizontal scrollbar also appears because the vertical scrollbar lowers the listview width for the tiles. Is there a way i can have the tiles autoresize to fill the listview?

See example image:

What currently happens:
[image]

What i want to happen:
[image]

I tried setting the width to 100% but that doesnt work. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this `WPF` or `Windows Forms`?

Comment: The application is Windows Forms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no direct way to detect that the scrollbar became visible.  An indirect way though, write an event handler for the ClientSizeChanged event:

```
    private void listView1_ClientSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        listView1.TileSize = new Size(listView1.ClientSize.Width, listView1.TileSize.Height);
    }
```

Also change the DPI setting on your machine to verify that your tile size is still appropriate.  That normally changes the size of the controls.  ClientSize.Width is your friend.