# C# how to show Items in TILE structure

Tags: c#

I need to show `ListView` items in `TILE` structure.. (like a clickable product view )

I am new to C#, therefore I couldn't find a property for changing `ListView` items column width. What is the `ListView` property to control item width?

```
listView1.Items.Clear();

while (rd.Read())
{
    //MessageBox.Show(rd.GetString(1));
    listView1.Items.Add(rd.GetString(1), 3);
}
```

Comment: You need to be more specific. First of all tag correctly like Winforms, WPF or ...., Then post some code about what you did already and where you are stuck

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8z85th0(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: great work.. Thnx

Answer (score 0):

If I dint get you wrong, you can change the column width something like this:

```
listView1.Columns[0].Width = something;
listView1.Columns[1].Width = something;
//so on
```

**UPDATE :**

Also these posts might be helpfull to you..

[C# ListView Tile Width 100%?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463774/c-sharp-listview-tile-width-100)

[C# ListView Column Width Auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257500/c-sharp-listview-column-width-auto)